# comparing current time to UTC

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to query the DB for the opening time of a store.

The `open_at` when queried from the DB returns:

```
2000-01-01 16:18:00 +0000
```

When I run `Time.current` it returns

```
Tue, 14 Jun 2016 16:32:46 CEST +02:00
```

Now I'm trying to do:

```
store.business_hours.where('open_at <= ?', Time.current)
```

it returns an empty ActiveRecord array as such:

```
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
```

now what I'm trying to do is make it so that the open_at in-fact shows, and that it's able to understand the time zone difference.

Comment: Can you try `store.business_hours.where('open_at <= Time.current)` ?

Comment: Can you try store.business_hours.where(:open_at <= Time.current).  Rails should be able to compare the 2 without issue as I just tried the following in the console:  t = "2000-01-01 16:18:00 +0000".   t <= Time.current => true

Comment: Do you need to use `Time.now.utc`?

Comment: @ruby_newbie it returns comparison of Symbol with ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone failed

Comment: can you try calling .to_s on the open_at method?  In retrospect I passed in a string.